# Observables: How does first behave whith other operators?

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I have been searching for an answer but I couldn't find anything conclusive.
What does happen when I use `first` operator on an `observable` an then pipe other operators over it like `swtichMap` or `map`.

What I know, when I use `first` and then subscribe it will be alive until first value is returned:

```
myObs.first().subscribe(console.log);
// I shouldn't be worried about unsiscribe
myObs.pipe(first()).subscibe(console.log);
// The same here
```

But what happens when I pipe other functions, I will split the question in two points, first, what happens when I use simple operators (operators that doesn't return other observable):

```
// 1. Will this subscription end on first emitted value?
myObs.first().pipe(map(data => return data.content)).subscribe(console.log);

// 2. Is this different from (1)
myObs.pipe(first(), map(data => return data.content)).subscribe(console.log);

// 3. Will this subscription end on first emitted value?
myObs.pipe(map(data => return data.content), first()).subscribe(console.log);
```

What I think happens:

- (1) and (2) are the same and the subscription will be alive forever if we don't unsubscibe, but it will only emit one value. Inner subscription will end but outer subscriptions will not.
- (3) The opposite of (1,2), inner subscription will live forever and outer will end after first emit value. Is there any inner subscription? or am I wrong?

And for last, would anything change using `switchMap()`? If we use `switchMap()` instead of `flatMap()` it will end inner subscriptions with every new value but what happens with the quesitons above?

EDIT: Should we use `first()` as the begining of pipes and in the end to make sure subscriptions will end?

```
// 3. Has these any sense?
myObs.pipe(frist(), map(data => return data.content), first()).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I looks like you wanted to use `flatMap ` instead of `map()` everywhere

Answer (score 1):

If you use `switchMap`, `concatMap` or `mergeMap` (`flatMap`) after first() it might lead to multiple events dependent on your code, so check you code if it generates events. Regular `map` cannot lead to new event.

```
// this stream emits event every second.
stream$.pipe(
  first(),
  mergeMap(() => interval(1000)
);
```

There is no need to put `first` at start and at the end. Put it at start if you know that you don't have stream in stream (don't call `mergeMap` like operators). Put at `first` at the end in other cases.

Comment: I know with ``map`` I will not get any new events, but I'm asking about automatic unsubscription. Imagine my stream will always return just one value, will the point ``2`` subscription finish after first emit value? I think it won't

Comment: @Gonzo, I believe, you don't need to unsubscribe in case `2`. This is popular  post about this https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87